# Access Ajax Call response PHP via jqXhr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax call in Jquery to get a user logged in to the website.

JQUERY call looks like as below

```
$("#login-form").validate({
    submitHandler : function(form) {
        var request;
        // bind to the submit event of our form
        // lets select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $(form).find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $(form).serialize();
        // lets disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        $('#submit_btn_log').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" 
        style="height:20px"/> Please Wait...');

        // fire off the request to /form.php
        request = $.ajax({
                url: "social_login/login",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
        });
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // log a message to the console
                //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                window.setTimeout(hide_modal, 1000);
                window.setTimeout(function()
                        {window.location.reload()},1000); 
                });
        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, 
                errorThrown);
        });
        // callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
                // reenable the inputs
                $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });            
     }
});
```

PHP function to verify credentials are:

```
function login( array $data )
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
    if( !empty( $data ) ){
        // Trim all the incoming data:
        $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);           
        // escape variables for security
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  
         $trimmed_data['email'] );
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  
         $trimmed_data['password'] );

        if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }
        $password = md5( $password );
        $query = "SELECT user_ids, names, emails, createds FROM users where 
         emails = '$email' and passwords = '$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if( $count >= 1){
            $_SESSION = $data;
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here, i am facing the issue that whenever user enters **Wrong Credentials** then even **alert(textStatus)** in **request.done** gives success and modal closes.

Means i am not able to verify whether user has entered wrong credentials. On providing right credentials modal closes and login happpens.

How can i check **return** value by function on **.done** function.

Comment: `done` will fire whenever something is returned, regardless of what it is. You have to return the logged in status, and than catch it in the `done` callback and figure out what to do then.

Comment: that is what i am not able to figure out... as per concept i know... but how to implemet this way i am confused.

Comment: Could you not just use the success callback rather than done?

Comment: @Ajaypayne .. can u write small piece of code please

Comment: I would suggest you would validate the response received in `.done(...)` callback and verify whether credentials are correct or wrong , based on that you can proceed with sign-on process.

Comment: if i am doing `alert(response)` then always it is blank :(  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example

In your php script return json

```
<?php
$json=['success'=>'','error'=>''];
//after some action
if(1){
$json['success']='ok';  
}else{
    $json['error']='Your error message!';   
}


echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

In  JQuery set dataType json

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function(data) {
    if(data.success=='ok'){
    //close the dialog
    }else{
    //show errors
alert(data.error);
or console.log(data.error);
    }
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

This is not exact answer of your question but it will help you to understand the process I think!